# Power BI - custom Column to get Levels

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have created the cost account like this

And this is how it looks in Power BI when data imported.

I am not sure how to develop a custom column in Power BI that can return levels and at the same time maintain relationship.

For instance

1. For SITE WORKS I get a value “Level 0” in custom column
2. For Substructure I get a value “Level 1” in custom column [Child to SITE WORKS Parent]
3. For Excavation in unclassified soil I get a value “Level 2” in custom column [Child to Substructure Parent]

The column is indicating the child belongs to which parent. If  is 762, then it is a “Level 1” of to 762 “Level 1”

Can someone please help with this use case?

Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working in Power BI, you might want to try this approach that uses DAX.

This method could probably be better for two reasons:

1. It is much more straightforward.
2. It could automatically accommodate future level changes like the one where you added the NBA level. (With my earlier M-based approach, you'd have to edit the code if you added another level--that is certainly not optimal.)

So, try this instead:

Load your original table into Power BI. Then switch to the Data view to look at it.

[image]

Then click *Column Tools* > *New Column* and enter this into the formula box:

```
Hierarchy = PATH(Sheet1[acct_id],Sheet1[parent_acct_id])
```

Then click *New Column* again and enter this into the formula box:

```
Level = "Level " & CONVERT(LEN(Sheet1[Hierarchy])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1[Hierarchy],"|","")),STRING)
```

Then either hit the Enter key or click basically anywhere outside the formula box.

That should do it. You should see something like this:

[image]

[You might find this helpful](https://curbal.com/blog/glossary/path-dax-example). I did.

Answer (score 0):

**This is updated per your recent comment that you added NBA.**
It takes a different, perhaps better(?) approach than my original answer.

I started with a table like yours in Power Query:

[image]

I called it "Table" and referenced it for the following:

```
let
    Source = Table,
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each try if [parent_acct_id] = "" then [acct_short_name] else Source[acct_short_name]{List.PositionOf(Source[acct_id],[parent_acct_id])} & "." & [acct_short_name] otherwise [acct_short_name]),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each  try #"Added Custom"[Custom]{List.PositionOf(#"Added Custom"[acct_id],[parent_acct_id])} & "." & [acct_short_name] otherwise [Custom] ),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom.2", each try #"Added Custom1"[Custom.1]{List.PositionOf(#"Added Custom1"[acct_id],[parent_acct_id])} & "." & [acct_short_name] otherwise [Custom.1]),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Custom.3", each "Level " & Text.From(List.Count(List.FindText(Text.ToList([Custom.2]),".")))),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom3",{"acct_name", "Custom.2", "Custom.3"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"Custom.2", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

It gives me a result like this:

[image]

Assuming you still have your table in Power Query as you shared it in you post, you should only need to change my reference to Table1 in order to use my code.

Comment: Thanks heaps @Marc Pincince. There's a slight change in table, I have added "NBA" at Level 0 & "SITE WORKS, CONCRETE WORKS" etc under NBA. Please refer to the "Power Query Editor" snap for the change. Can you please modify your content accordingly in Advanced Editor please?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me out Marc Pincince. I used the same code you provided and I'm getting a slightly different result as below
[snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtWdi.png)

```
let
    Source = ALL_XER,
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([TABLE REF] = "ACCOUNT") and ([Column1] <> "%T")),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Filtered Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Promoted Headers", each ([#"%F"] = "%R")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"acct_descr", "", "_1", "_2", "_3", "_4", "_5", "_6", "_7", "_8", "_9", "_10", "_11", "_12", "_13", "_15", "_16", "_17", "_18", "_19", "_20", "_21", "_22", "_23", "_24", "_25", "_26", "_27", "_28", "_29", "_30", "_31", "_32", "_33", "_34", "_35", "_36", "_37", "_38", "_39", "_40", "_41", "_42", "_43", "_44", "_45", "_46", "_47", "_48", "_49", "_50", "_51", "_52", "_53", "_54", "_55", "_14"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Columns", {"acct_id"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Duplicates", "Custom", each try if [parent_acct_id] = "" then [acct_short_name] else Source[acct_short_name]{List.PositionOf(Source[acct_id],[parent_acct_id])}&"."&[acct_short_name] otherwise [acct_short_name]),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each  try #"Added Custom"[Custom]{List.PositionOf(#"Added Custom"[acct_id],[parent_acct_id])} & "." & [acct_short_name] otherwise [Custom] ),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom.2", each try #"Added Custom1"[Custom.1]{List.PositionOf(#"Added Custom1"[acct_id],[parent_acct_id])} & "." & [acct_short_name] otherwise [Custom.1]),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Custom.3", each "Level " & Text.From(List.Count(List.FindText(Text.ToList([Custom.2]),".")))),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom3",{"acct_name", "Custom.2", "Custom.3"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"Custom.2", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Comment: Try replacing both remaining occurrences of `Sources` with `#"Removed Duplicates"` in your #"Added Custom" line.

Comment: I meant `Source`, not `Sources`.

Comment: No luck replacing #"Removed Duplicates" with "source" in #"Added Custom" line. Output is still the same. The code works perfectly fine up to level 02 but doesn't add "NBA" to level 03 entries & return "Level 02" instead of "level 03" in "Custom.3" col.

Comment: I think you did the reverse of what I was saying to do. Use this: `#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Duplicates", "Custom", each try if [parent_acct_id] = "" then [acct_short_name] else #"Removed Duplicates"[acct_short_name]{List.PositionOf(#"Removed Duplicates"[acct_id],[parent_acct_id])}&"."&[acct_short_name] otherwise [acct_short_name]),`

Comment: Thank you Marc, it works perfectly fine now. You are legend my friend.